# How to declare an object and iterate it in pug js?

Tags: html, frontend, pug, web-frontend

What's wrong in my code where I am trying to store some data in an object and iterate it. The code is

```
extends ../layouts/default-layout.pug

block variables
  -
    var blogPosts = [{
    tag: 'travel',
    title: '25 Things to See and Do in Barcelona',
    }, 
    {
    tag: 'travel',
    title: '25 Things to See and Do in Barcelona',
    },  
    {
    tag: 'travel',
    title: '25 Things to See and Do in Barcelona',
    }];

block content
 .row
    .col-md-6.text-center
        each val in blogPosts
              p= blogPosts.tag
```

It gives following error

```
Unexpected block variables
Details:
    code: PUG:UNEXPECTED_BLOCK
    msg: Unexpected block variables
    line: 3
    column: 1
    filename: C:\Users\Osman Rafi\Desktop\Pug-Sass-Starter\src\pug\pages\index.pug
    src: undefined
    toJSON: function () {
    return {
      code: this.code,
      msg: this.msg,
      line: this.line,
      column: this.column,
      filename: this.filename
    };
  }
```

How can I solve this problem ? Can you help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message states:

> Unexpected block variables

This means that the `../layouts/default-layout.pug` template you're extending doesn't have a `variables` block defined for Pug to place that content into.

You could declare a `variables` block on that `default-layout` template, or you could remove the `block variables` from this page and instead put the content at the top of the `content` block.